# Improve tag excerpt guidance

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki-excerpt

I find I'm rejecting a lot of suggested edits of tag wiki excerpts because they lack usage guidance.

I think that part of the problem is that the explanation of what should be in the excerpt is off to the right:

> #### What are Tag Wikis?
>
> The usage guidance, or tag wiki excerpt, is a short blurb that
> describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically.

But that's visually separated from the user's attention; right by the edit field there's just

> Usage guidance (excerpt)

Perhaps this label could be extended with a reminder (cribbed from the reject reason):

> Usage guidance (excerpt) - describe **why** and **when** this tag should be used

Comment: Maybe the [Ask a question template](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363051/578411) can be (ab)used?

Comment: Yeah, this wasn't clear in the previous guidelines - those allowed for just a simple description, and users are using those as examples for current edits.